# Scorecard to show total average per month

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I have a data source (coming from a Google Sheet) of engagements that has two columns:

- Submitted Date
- ID

Each row is a unique engagement.

I want to show a single Scorecard widget that has the total average # of engagements per month. For example, if:

- 2020-01 - 5 rows / engagements
- 2020-02 - 7 rows / engagements
- 2020-03 - 4 rows / engagements

Then the scorecard would show average of 5.33 rows/engagements.

Here is some sample data:

```
| Submitted Date | ID   |
|----------------|------|
| 2020-01-02     | ID01 |
| 2020-01-05     | ID02 |
| 2020-01-10     | ID03 |
| 2020-01-12     | ID04 |
| 2020-01-21     | ID05 |
| 2020-02-01     | ID06 |
| 2020-02-02     | ID07 |
| 2020-02-05     | ID08 |
| 2020-02-15     | ID09 |
| 2020-02-16     | ID10 |
| 2020-02-17     | ID11 |
| 2020-02-21     | ID12 |
| 2020-03-10     | ID13 |
| 2020-03-15     | ID14 |
| 2020-03-20     | ID15 |
| 2020-03-25     | ID16 |
```

I know I can pre-process this data in another sheet in Google to create a table that shows # of rows per month and then in Data Studio I can create an average of that. I am trying to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudocode, the formula below is `COUNT(ID) / COUNT_DISTINCT(Year Month)` (in this case, `16 / 3`):

```
COUNT(ID) / COUNT_DISTINCT(TODATE(Submitted Date, "%Y%m"))
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/043053ec-612f-4f84-b9d6-cd9d904379a0) to demonstrate:

[image: 2]]

Answer (score -1):

Since each row is a unique engagement, first, I would extract the year-month from the Submitted Date column. Then I would count their occurrences and get the average value.

[table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Xzn.png)